# HTML5 <details> with "display: contents" in CSS Grid layout not working correctly with Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a set of `<details> > <summary>` elements arranged in a single row of a CSS Grid and I would like their content to be displayed after that row, each content spanning an entire new row.

I made it work with Safari and Firefox but I can't get Google Chrome span the entire row, so I would like to know if the problem lays in my code or if that's a Google Chrome bug, in which case I'll submit a bug report...

```css
/*** Layout ***/

.gcol-2 {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
 grid-gap: 1em;
}

.gcol-2 details { display: contents; }

/* fix for Firefox */
.gcol-2 details:not([open]) > :not(summary) { display: none; }

.gcol-2 details > summary {
 display: inline-block;
}

.gcol-2 details > div {
 justify-self: strech;
 grid-area: auto / 1 / span 1 / span 2;
}

/* it seems we absolutely need to use IDs here ... */
#r1c1, #r1c2 {
 grid-row-start: 1;
 align-self: center;
}

#r1c1 { justify-self: end; }
#r1c2 { justify-self: start; }

/* explicit ID not needed here but whatever ... */
#r2 {
 width: 100%;
 grid-area: 2 / 1 / span 1 / span 2;
}


/*** Styling ***/

.gcol-2 details > summary {
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #fff;
 background-color: dodgerblue;
 padding: 0 1.5em;
 line-height: 2.75em;
}

.gcol-2 details > summary { list-style: none; }
.gcol-2 details > summary::-webkit-details-marker { display: none; }

.gcol-2 details[open] > summary {
 background-color: mediumblue;
}

.info {
 padding: 2em;
 background-color: lightyellow;
}

/* explicit focus outline for testing tab order */
*:focus {
 outline: 3px solid pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="gcol-2">

 <details>
  <summary id="r1c1">Show content 1</summary>
  <div class="info">
   <h2>Content 1</h2>
   <p>Duis neque nisi, dapibus sed mattis et quis, nibh. Sed et dapibus nisl amet mattis, sed a rutrum accumsan sed. Suspendisse eu.
   <p><button type="button">Testing Tab order in the DOM</button>
  </div>
 </details>
 <hr id="r2">
 <details>
  <summary id="r1c2">Show content 2</summary>
  <div class="info">
   <h2>Content 2</h2>
   <p>Aenean ornare velit lacus, ac varius enim ullamcorper eu. Proin aliquam facilisis ante interdum congue. Integer mollis, nisl amet convallis, porttitor magna ullamcorper, amet egestas mauris. Ut magna finibus nisi nec lacinia. Nam maximus erat id euismod egestas. Pellentesque sapien ac quam.
   <p><button type="button">Testing Tab order in the DOM</button>
  </div>
</details>
</div>
```

Here's also a Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Fravadona/26vya3kb/

Comment: The bug has been confirmed by the Chromium devs
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=973074